# How to check if the user has selected multiple documents using Notes Formula Language?

Tags: lotusscript

The same thing is very simple while using LotusScript through like:

Set SelectedDocs = db.UnprocessedDocuments

and then get the count of SelectedDocs.

But for some reason I'm already using Notes Formula Language to perform something and now I'm required to figure out whether the user has selected one or more than one documents and based on that I have to perform specific course of action.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no such formula. The only way I could think of is to put your LotusScript in an agent and run it. If you leave the output in an environment variable, you can pick it up in Formula.

Answer (score 0):

Formula agents are executed on a per document basis. So it's not possible to detect the number of selected documents in a formula agent. You may or may not overcome this restriction by calling an LS or Java agent via [ToolsRunMacro] that gives you the count via environment or a profile doc - but that's bad practice and leads to very unclean code.
The best advice is probably to dismiss your formula and start over using Java